# "Root of Configuration" for GitOps and CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, configuration-management, gitops

In reading about configuration management, GitOps and CI/CD-Pipelines, I didn't find a good answer to the following question:

Who manages the configuration for the configuration management tools?

If, for instance, one were to use something like GitLab to manage applications in a Kubernetes cluster, while also running GitLab in a Kubernetes cluster, who manages the configuration of GitLab in an appropriately GitOps-y manner? Ideally, I guess, the tools would offer an option to manage their own configuration, acting as a "root of Co figuration", but I am not sure tools support this.

Does anyone have any sources or reading on this, recommended tools, architectures or the like?

Comment: No reason you can't manage the GitLab cluster itself in exactly the same way. There may be some operational concerns with this approach -- for example what do you do if GitLab becomes unavailable due to a bad configuration change? -- but there's no reason why it can't be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would I then use the managed GitLab instance for that? Or another tool that does not rely on a Git repository?